Removing the indentation from the chapters in the table of content
While using the following class file, I get an indentation on the chapters in the table of contents. I like to have an indentation on the section names, but not on the chapters.

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{thesis}  
\begin{document}                        
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents    
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\newpage
\chapter*{DEDICATION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\mainmatter                            
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{New Chapter}
\section{New section}
\end{document}                                                  

Here, the class file thesis.cls contains:
%%  This file was generated from the file `book.cls'.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{thesis}[2003/09/15]

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}   

\providecommand\@ptsize{}
\newcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1}
\newcommand{\@defaultparindent}{2em}
\newcommand{\@defaultrightskip}{\z@}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@draftdate \@draftdatefalse
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@openbib
\@openbibfalse
\newif\if@openright
\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
\newif\if@firstmain
\newif\if@appmatter

\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
\fi
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\DeclareOption{singlespace}{\renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1}}
\DeclareOption{1.5space}
   {\ifnum\@ptsize=0 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.25} \fi %
    \ifnum\@ptsize=1 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.21} \fi %
    \ifnum\@ptsize=2 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.24} \fi}
\DeclareOption{doublespace}
   {\ifnum\@ptsize=0 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.67} \fi %
    \ifnum\@ptsize=1 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.62} \fi %
    \ifnum\@ptsize=2 \renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.66} \fi}
\DeclareOption{draftdate}{\@draftdatetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility
\@openrighttrue
\else
\DeclareOption{openright}{\@openrighttrue}
\DeclareOption{openany}{\@openrightfalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      }%
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}

\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,doublespace,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}

\ProcessOptions
\usepackage{calc}
\input{bk1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\@defaultbaselinestretch}
\normalsize
%% next set of lengths are set for 12pt only
%%Changed \topmargin, \textheight, \footskip, \headsep, \textwidth to shrink margins and conform to standards, These values worked for me, but could be changed, or use geometry package?.  TSH
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.35in}

\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in - \topskip}   %Changed from 9.25in.  BCR
  \newcounter{tempc}   \setcounter{tempc}{\textheight}
  \newcounter{tempcc}  \setcounter{tempcc}{\baselineskip}
  \setcounter{tempc}{\value{tempc}/\value{tempcc}}
  \setlength{\textheight}{\baselineskip*\value{tempc}+\topskip}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.08in}
\setlength{\headheight}{\topskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}%{ \paperheight/2 - \textheight/2 - 2in/2 - \topmargin - \headheight} % This is a work around for 

\newlength{\uppermargin}
  \setlength{\uppermargin}{1in + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.35in}%\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight - 0.25in - \textheight - \uppermargin}
%
\newlength{\uppermargintwo}
  \setlength{\uppermargintwo}{2in - \uppermargin - \baselineskip}
\newlength{\uppermarginfour}
  \setlength{\uppermarginfour}{4in - \uppermargin - \topskip - \baselineskip}
%%
\setlength{\parindent}{\@defaultparindent}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}

\newlength{\headwidth}\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\newlength{\headrulewidth}\setlength{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newlength{\headruleskip}\setlength{\headruleskip}{1pt}
%%%
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
\if@draftdate
  \def\ps@empty{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {\hfil{\slshape\leftmark}%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \markboth{Draft Date: \today}{Draft Date: \today}
    }
  \def\ps@plain{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
    \def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
    \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {\hfil{\slshape\leftmark}%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \markboth{Draft Date: \today}{Draft Date: \today}
    }
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {\thepage\hfill{\slshape\leftmark}%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \def\@oddhead{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}%
                      {{\slshape\rightmark}\hfill\thepage%
                       \vskip\headruleskip%
                       \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}}
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \markboth{Draft Date: \today}{Draft Date: \today}
    }
\else \if@twoside
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in} % this seems correct -nbp
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.in} % this seems correct -nbp
  \def\ps@headings{
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage} %this works!
    \def\@oddhead{\hfil\thepage}
    \def\sectionmark##1{
      \markright{\MakeTextUppercase{
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ 
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\else
  \def\ps@headings{
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \markright{}
    }

\fi  % End the \if@twoside statements
\fi  % End the \if@draftdate statements
%
%
\newcommand*\chaptermark[1]{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand\thepart         {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand\thechapter      {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection      {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection .\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\newcommand\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage
            \@mainmatterfalse\pagestyle{plain}\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{\cleardoublepage
       \@mainmattertrue\pagestyle{headings}\pagenumbering{arabic}
       % \@firstmaintrue \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
% {\protect\hb@xt@\hsize{\@chapapp\hfill}}
       \@firstmainfalse}
\newcommand\backmatter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                       \@mainmatterfalse}
                       
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \if@appmatter %% What does this do?
                           \refstepcounter{chapter}
                           \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
                           \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
                           {\protect\hb@xt@\hsize{\@chapapp\space\thechapter\hfill} #1}% This applies to the Appendices
                         \else
                           \refstepcounter{chapter}
                           \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
                           \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
                                   {\protect\hskip 1.5em \numberline{\thechapter}#1}% This applies to Normal Chapters
                         \fi
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}% This applies to the abstract
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{2.0\baselineskip}}
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{2.0\baselineskip}}
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}
                      \@afterheading
                      \parindent=\@defaultparindent
                      \rightskip=\@defaultrightskip
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
   \if@mainmatter
\ifnum\@ptsize=0   %0 is for 10 pt
\LARGE
\else \huge
\fi
%
      \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
      \par\nobreak
      \vskip 20\p@
      \else
        \vspace*{-\topskip}%
      \fi
    \else
      \vspace*{-\topskip}%
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum\@ptsize=0 
\LARGE
\else \Huge
\fi
%
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \vskip 4\p@
      \else
        \vskip 40\p@
      \fi
    \else
      \vskip 40\p@
    \fi
    \parindent=\@defaultparindent
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                   \parindent=\@defaultparindent
                   \rightskip=\@defaultrightskip
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  \vspace*{\uppermargintwo}
  \vspace*{-\topskip}
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \begin{center}\bfseries #1\end{center}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
    \parindent=\@defaultparindent
  }}
  
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
%% nbp: i added the following lines to change chapter size with 10pt font
        {\normalfont
            \ifnum\@ptsize=0 
                \large
            \else
                \Large
            \fi
        \bfseries}}  %needed for 10pt option
                             
                                      

\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \@appmattertrue
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\@addtoreset{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@equation}
\newcounter{figure}[chapter]
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
               {\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{figure*}
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}[chapter]
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
% Length for use with captions
\newlength\captionwidth
%
% This version of the caption definition
% places 5 percent white space around the
% caption on each side of the text.
%
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\captionwidth{\hsize*9/10}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\captionwidth
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfill \parbox{\hsize*9/10}{#1: #2}\hfill}
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
\long\def\undertext#1{\hbox to\hsize{\hfill\vtop{\hbox{#1}\kern 1pt \hrule}\hfill}}
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\normalfont\large\MakeTextUppercase\contentsname
        \@mkboth{      \MakeTextUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeTextUppercase\contentsname}}
   \vspace{ -1.3cm} %%one line between title and body, TSH
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}
    \begingroup
      \setlength\@tempdima{3em}
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}
    \endgroup
    \parindent=\@defaultparindent \rightskip=\@defaultrightskip
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} \small \normalsize
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \advance \leftskip \@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      {#1}\nobreak\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
       \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
       mu$}\hfill \nobreak
      \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\@defaultbaselinestretch} \small \normalsize
    \parindent=\@defaultparindent \rightskip=\@defaultrightskip
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.0em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{5.3em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{8.5em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{11.5em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{13.5em}{6em}}
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \chapter*{\normalfont\large\MakeTextUppercase{\listfigurename}}
    \@mkboth{\MakeTextUppercase{\listfigurename}}
            {\MakeTextUppercase{\listfigurename}}
    \begin{spacing}{1.1}
     \vspace{ -1.3cm} %one line, TSH
      \@starttoc{lof}
    \end{spacing}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\@defaultbaselinestretch} \small\normalsize
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \chapter*{\normalfont\large\MakeTextUppercase{\listtablename}}
    \@mkboth{\MakeTextUppercase{\listtablename}}
            {\MakeTextUppercase{\listtablename}}
    \begin{spacing}{1.1}
    \vspace{ -1.3cm} %one line TSH
      \@starttoc{lot}%
    \end{spacing}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\@defaultbaselinestretch} \small\normalsize
    }
\let\l@table\l@figure


\newcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcommand\chaptername{CHAPTER}

\endinput

\usepackage{setspace}

%% End of file `wmthesis.cls'.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



Change
 {\protect\hskip 1.5em \numberline{\thechapter}#1}% This applies to Normal Chapters
                     

to
 {\protect\hskip 0pt \numberline{\thechapter}#1}% This applies to Normal Chapters

Or maybe just eliminate the \hskip, but I guess 0pt should be OK.
I would not recommend using this class. I would be very surprised if it didn't cause headaches, if only by inserting spurious spaces in strange places.

Thank you. I agree with your recommendation not to use this class. Just using the class report with some relevant customization was better. By the way, one more thing, the indentation of the sections under the chapters (in ToC) remains the same. Can you please check how to reduce that as well?

@raf You probably need to alter the lines like \newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.0em}{2.3em}} But the class is adding spurious spaces everywhere, so worrying about the spacing in the ToC seems a bit pointless?

Thanks. Here is the full class file if you like to check it: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ntkmfcmxfyqy#e97801.
I tried to reduce it in a hurry to make an MWE.

@raf I already recommended against using it. That's what I recommend: don't use it. It does a heap of things it ought not do which will cause you problems.

Thank you. I get your point.
